# Beamer background does not match pdf background when including pdf as image

Tags: pdf, transparency, includegraphics

I want to include some pdfs in my Latex beamer presentation like so:

```
\begin{figure}  
    \includegraphics[]{./path/to/image.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Unfortunetaly there is a clear change in color between my beamer slide background and the background of the pdf image. I thought the background of a pdf is transparent/non-existant?

To give you an idea how it looks:
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfGU3.png

It does not seem to bad on this image but if you zoom in it gets clearly visible.

Is there anyway to prevent this or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that the background of that included pdf actually is transparent. It clearly depends on how the PDF is made.

Comment: The pdf was generated by draw.io. As far as i know the background of an exported pdf is transparent by default in draw.io.

Comment: Only one way to find out, post the PDF.

Comment: Just created and downloaded a fast diagram from draw.io, it clearly have a white background.

Comment: Is there a way to change this? Either before exporting or later on in Latex?

Comment: Usually LaTeX cannot change the included PDF. BTW: I don't know what you are doing on your diagram, but from that sniplet, that is something LaTeX can draw on its own. That way you can have complete control, plus the fonts match the ones you use in your document.  See for example http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/charts/

Comment: My diagrams get much more complicated which is why i prefer draw.io for the ease-of-use and the speed. Also i like draw.io diagrams aesthetically.

Comment: For what its worth I cant see your png in any of my browsers so cant comment on how you are using it but transparent png embeded in pdf is often a problem since archival pdf discouraged transparency. PNG is a format designed for alpha transparency in html and graphics so I would suggest keeping to that as its designed usage. An alternative is the opacity of TikZ objects on beamer slides (just expect you may have some downstream issues if converted to PDF)